# ObjLoader.loadObj not takinng inputstream as argument

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using libgdx  0.9.8 and trying to load .obj files as Mesh.But as specified in various tutorials and in the documentation its not taking `Stream` as paramtetr rather its asking for FileHandle. What should be passsed is it because of the version ?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using this code, but I am still struggling with texture loading:

```
     ObjLoader model = new ObjLoader();
     meshCar = model.loadObj(
             Gdx.files.internal("data/car_white.obj"), 
             Gdx.files.internal("data/car_white"),
             true
             );
```